# Рисование в элементе view

Tags: android

Можно ли использовать canvas внутри какого-либо view? Находил примеры, когда можно рисовать примитивы на всём экране, при этом нельзя использовать контролы (кнопки, текст, прочее).

Всё, проблема решена! Неправильно указал путь к классу, он был вложен в активити. Ещё немного про custom view скажу - желательно перегружать onMeasure и onDraw методы.

Answer (score 2):

У вас `View` из `canvas` и состоит, если `onDraw` метод посмотрите:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
}
```

Поверх него что угодно можете рисовать.

Comment: Ну это вы про свой собственный класс наследник view говорите. Я имел ввиду любой готовый view, например, imageview. Но всё равно спасибо за ответ. )

Comment: Или может есть возможность объект класса наследника view использовать в layout как обычный view? Впрочем, мне не удалось это реализовать, говорит:

    Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class healthy_eating.healthy_eating.MyView

Comment: @neurocore есть. <имя_пакет.МойКласс/> например

Comment: Так и написано у меня в axml:

<healthy_eating.healthy_eating.MyView
            p1:id="@+id/myView"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_below="@id/textView1" />

Внутри relativelayout разумеется

Comment: @neurocore а свою вьюху правильно написали? Там 3 конструктора?

Comment: Не пугайтесь, на шарпах пишу:

public MyView(Context context) : base (context)
public MyView(Context ctx, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(ctx, attrs)
public MyView(Context ctx, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(ctx, attrs)